# Find nearest SUM amount from table SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Query**

```
Declare @table1 TABLE (accountno varchar(max), saved_amount decimal)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
('001',25),
('002',5)

Declare @table2 TABLE (accountno varchar(max), payamount decimal,ilno int)

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
('001',10,1),
('001',10,2),
('001',10,3),
('001',10,4),
('002',10,1),
('002',10,2);

WITH aa
AS (
    SELECT a.*
        ,b.ilno
        ,b.payamount
        ,SUM(payamount) OVER (
            PARTITION BY a.accountno ORDER BY CAST(a.accountno AS INT)
                ,ilno
            ) AS total_amount
    FROM @table1 a
    LEFT JOIN @table2 b ON a.accountno = b.accountno
    )
    ,bb
AS (
    SELECT accountno
        ,MAX(ilno) AS ilno
    FROM aa
    WHERE saved_amount >= total_amount
    GROUP BY accountno
    )
SELECT a.* FROM aa a INNER JOIN bb b on a.accountno =b.accountno AND a.ilno = b.ilno
```

**Result**

```
accountno | saved_amount | ilno | payamount | total_amount
---------------------------------------------------------- 
001       |      25      |   2  |    10     |     20
```

**Expected Result**

```
accountno | saved_amount | ilno | payamount | total_amount
---------------------------------------------------------- 
001       |      25      |   2  |    10     |     20
002       |      5       |   1  |    10     |     10
```

What I want is

- If saved_amount is less than the first ilno, then get the first ilno else
  get the highest ilno where saved_amount>=total_amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a running total that you compare with the saved amount. You want the highest running total that doesn't exceed the saved amount. But in case even the initial pay amount exceeds the saved amount already, you want to default to this record. So the main task is to find a way of ranking the records. In my query I do it like this:

1. Prefer records where the running total does not exceed the saved amount.
2. Then look at the abolute of their difference and take the smallest.

There are certainly other ways that achieve the same. Maybe even methods that you find more readable. Then just adjust the order by clause in the ranking query.

```
with summed as 
(
  select 
    t1.*,
  from @table1 t1
  join
  (
    select 
      ilno,
      payamount,
      sum(payamount) over (partition by accountno order by ilno) as total_amount
    from @table2 
  ) on t2.accountno = t1.accountno
)
, ranked as
(
  select summed.*,
  row_number() over (partition by accountno
                     order by case when saved_amount >= total_amount then 1 else 2 end,
                              abs(saved_amount - total_amount)
                    ) as rn
)
select *
from ranked
where rn = 1;
```

This is not the "nearest sum", as you said in the title, but the one that obeys the specified rules. So with a saved amount of 100 and paid amounts of first 1 and then 100, you'd get the record with a total of 1 (which is 99 less than the saved amount) and not the one with a total of 101 (which is only 1 more than the saved amount).

Answer (score 0):

Other way to solve using flags:

1. first calculated one flag to point if `saved_amount >= payamount` for current row
2. calculated three more flags:

   - `group_flag` to show is there a case where `saved_amount >= payamount` for the given `accountno`
3. `[min_ilno]`  and `[max_ilno]` for given account

Having this flags, the final result set is calculated easily. Here is the code:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT a.*
        ,b.ilno
        ,b.payamount
        ,SUM(payamount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.accountno ORDER BY ilno) AS total_amount
        ,IIF(a.saved_amount >= SUM(payamount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.accountno ORDER BY ilno), 1, 0) AS [flag]
    FROM @table1 a
    LEFT JOIN @table2 b 
        ON a.accountno = b.accountno
),
DataSourceFinal AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,MAX(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY accountno) as [group_flag]
          ,MIN(IIF(flag = 0 ,ilno, NULL)) OVER (PARTITION BY accountno) as [min_ilno]
          ,MAX(IIF(flag = 1 ,ilno, NULL)) OVER (PARTITION BY accountno) as [max_ilno]
    FROM DataSource
)
SELECT accountno, saved_amount, ilno, payamount, total_amount
FROM DataSourceFinal
WHERE ([group_flag] = 1 AND [ilno] = [max_ilno])
    OR ([group_flag] = 0 AND [ilno] = [min_ilno]);
```

and the output:

[image]